# sync sent mail between iPhone and mail.app

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, email

Can I set up my mac/iPhone/mobile me to sync the mails I've sent on my iPhone back to my mail.app on my mac?

I use two email addresses: an IMAP (gmail) address and a microsoft exchange address.

On the other hand, I can't even see the mails I've sent on my iPhone in the mail app on the iPhone, it only shows mail.app sent mails.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution for Gmail:

Gesendet must the the *label of the mailbox that you use for sent mail on the iPhone*. (info: gesendet is German for sent)

I believe the default label is named **`Sent Messages`** created once you set up Gmail on your iPhone using IMAP.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help since I've set up my mail.app not to show gmail labels...